# Who is the uncredited actor leading the squad in the Valerian movie?

Tags: valerian-and-city-thousand-planets

Near the end  of the movie, when the squad of soldiers are at the wall and then attacked by the k-trons, who is the actor leading the squad? His face reminds me of a bad guy or villain in some other movie/series. Is it Tron's David Warner?

Comment: A screenshot or a timestamp would be nice to confirm who you're talking about.

Answer (score 8):

This is [Captain Kris](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/a5f4395b-86ab-4e73-9006-35a14f35c1fd), played by [Alexandre Willaume](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0929654/).

[image]